# How to set the white color to google+ log in button?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using google+ login for my app. I want to change the color of button from red to [white](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#matching).Here is my xml code.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 

    >
```

Comment: android:background="@android:color/white"

Comment: It's not changing all the background i already tried this. U can see the document about sign-in button [here.](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) I want to use white button.

Comment: Tell me what is the syntax to use [data-theme](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way

```
signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- white button -->
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:colorScheme="light" />

<!-- blue button -->
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:colorScheme="dark" />
```